# Ubuntu setup cronjob every 5 minuetes not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5.3

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I want to set up cron job for my laravel services. this is how I set up

`5 * * * * php /var/www/myapp/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

and in my laravel app kernel.php

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

         $schedule->command('email:send')
            ->dailyAt('03:30');
         $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyFiveMinutes();

    }
```

it did not trigger, I don't know why it did not trigger the command

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `5` is the notation of "execute when value *is* five". use `*/5` for "execute when value is *divisible* by five", e.g. every five minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/myapp/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I tried that when I refresh my database it keeps inserting to my table, I don't why it behave lik this that keeps inserting...looks like 5 seconds ? maybe of my queue:work ?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: yeah the queue:work that makes hung up my database I just remove it